# Fetch DNS error and Error 404 with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium

Well, i'm currently developping a Google Chrome extension and i need to fetch all the DNS and 404 error to make a redirection. The problem is simply that i really don't see how it's possible...

If it's a domain error i want to fetch the domain name and for a 404 error i want to fetch the name page.

Example :

Bad Domain : http://www.justforthetest.com/ => Fetch justforthetest

404 Error : http://www.valeriemates.com/professinal.html => Fetch professinal

Hope someone could provide me some helps...
Thanks in advance !

Comment: What information is needed to make the redirection? And most sites have a custom 404 page, and Chrome does not yet allow access to request & response headers.

Comment: I have edit my post to provide you more info ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the most I was able to do is to send a new XHR request to this URL and check returned status. For wrong domains status seems to be `0`, for 404 pages it is `404`.

**background.html**

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    if(changeInfo.status == "loading") {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", tab.url, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if(xhr.status == 0) {
                    console.log("wrong domain:", tab.url);
                } else if(xhr.status == 404) {
                    console.log("404 page:", tab.url);
                } else if(xhr.status == 200) {
                    console.log("regular page:", tab.url);
                }
            }
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
});
```

Comment: Not a bad idea, but i need to put this as an event isn't it ?

How can i create an event which check when i change web page ?

Comment: @Sindar ok, I put it inside `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`

Comment: And if i want to make a redirection when there is an error, i need to change the tab.url before the xhr.send() ?

Comment: @Sindar You would need to run `chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: "http://new_url.com"})` inside `xhr.onreadystatechange` (in place of those `console.log` alerts)

Comment: In that case you might want to add a check for chrome special pages, otherwise you might redirect the chrome extensions page for example (anything that starts with 'chrome' worked for me)